# Asp.net Validation. Only allow user to enter specific numbers in a text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Fund9" 
             runat="server" 
             columns="4" 
             MaxLength="3" Value="" /> 
<asp:RangeValidator ControlToValidate="Fund9" 
                    MinimumValue="100" 
                    MaximumValue="100" 
                    Type="Integer" 
                    ErrorMessage="Fund 9 must be 0 or 100" 
                    Text="Must be 100% if selected" runat="server" /></td></tr>
```

As you can see the validation on the above text box only allows the user to enter the number 100. I need it so the user can also enter 0 but no other options. I would appriciate some advice on this.

Comment: if you can ONLY have 100 or 0, why not have a drop down?

Comment: Due to design issues being forced on me it has to be a text box.

Comment: Ugh.  If you're forced into a textbox, look at a `RegularExpressionValidator`

Comment: I'd hate to be on your team..lol sounds like someone whom is in charge cannot think outside of the box.. anyway.. there are many ways you can accomplish this especially using some of the KeyPress Events for example..

Comment: Then you need to use a `CustomValidator`.

Comment: `Fund 9 must be blank or 100"` can you explain this message or can the user also enter nothing and have the validation pass..?

Comment: It should say Fund 9 must be 0 or 100. My mistake.

Comment: @MethodMan think outside the textbox : )

Comment: It was downvoted to -4 a few minutes after i put it up. Not sure why. @win gave me the answer i was looking for anyway. Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RegularExpressionValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If it is required to enter, you can combine it with [RequiredFieldValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) too.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Fund9"
    runat="server"
    Columns="4"
    MaxLength="3" Value="" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="Fund9RegularExpressionValidator"
    runat="server"
    ValidationExpression="^(0|100)$"
    ErrorMessage="Fund 9 must be 0 or 100" ControlToValidate="Fund9"
    Text="Must be 100% if selected" Display="Dynamic" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit"
    OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />

<%-- RequiredFieldValidator is optional --%>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ControlToValidate="Fund9" Text="Required"
    ErrorMessage="Required is required." runat="Server"
    ID="Fund9RequiredFieldValidator" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like this gives me exactly the functionality I was looking for!

Comment: @JD88: a `RegularExpressionValidator` works also. But note that it doesn't validate empty text (as opposed to the `CustomValidator`), so you need another `RequiredFieldValidator`. Have you tried the `CustomValidator` approach as well? Did it work or  what was the problem with it?

Comment: I tried the CustomValidator you suggested bellow but i couldn't get it working. Time is an issue for me today so i went with the above option as it worked straight away. It also seems to do the trick for for empty text ( I presume you mean when the text box is left blank) when i add in the RequiredFieldValidator suggested as optional above.

Comment: @JD88: maybe you have not added a `ClientValidationFunction` as mentioned in my answer, so you always have  a postback for validation. If you have code that modifies the `TextBox` in `Page_Load`(f.e. some databinding stuff) then the `ServerValidate` event is not triggered.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter. That makes sense, I do have other code working on that textbox.

Comment: Then put that code in the appropriate event handler(f.e. `TextChanged`), don't use `Page_Load` for your business logic, only for the initial databinding stuff which you wrap in a `if(!IsPostBack)...`.check.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [`CustomValidator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ValidatFund" 
    ControlToValidate="Fund9" ValidateEmptyText="true"
    OnServerValidate="ValidateFund" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="Fund 9 must be 0 or 100" >
</asp:CustomValidator>


protected void ValidateFund(Object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsValid = e.Value.Trim() == "0" || e.Value.Trim() == "100";
}
```

You can additionally provide a [`ClientValidationFunction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in javascript.